# face detection while recording video using firebase ml-kit

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

I want to detect faces while recording a video and wants to save video with overlay stickers.

Currently,I'm using Firebase ml-kit for face detection
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit/app

I'm able to detect face on live camera. But the camera freezes if I initiate MediaRecorder class to record video.

```
mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
cameraSource.unLockCamera();
mMediaRecorder.setCamera(cameraSource.getCamera());
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
CamcorderProfile mProfile=CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
mMediaRecorder.setProfile(mProfile);
```

Is anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Did you found any solution ?